Continuity assumption in the definition of regularity structure
A regularity structure is defined as a couple $(T, G)$ consisting of

a graded linear space $T = \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} T_\alpha$, where $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded from below and locally finite, and each $T_\alpha$ is a Banach space (with norm $\| \cdot \|_\alpha$);
a group $G$ of continuous linear operators $T \to T$ such that for each $\alpha \in A$, $\tau \in T_\alpha$ and $\Gamma \in G$, one has
$$ \Gamma \tau - \tau \in \bigoplus_{\beta < \alpha} T_\beta $$

In the above definition, what does the continuity of $\Gamma$ refer to? There is no obvious topology on $T$.

$T$ inherits a topology from the Banach space structure on the homogeneous components $T_\alpha$. One way to see this is to note that for any $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$T_{<\gamma} = \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A, \alpha < \gamma} T_\alpha$$
is a Banach space for any of the norms obtained by taking an $\ell^p$-direct sum since the index set we sum over is finite. Since the topologies obtained for different $p$ coincide, we have a good choice of topology on $T_{< \gamma}$. Then one can equip $T$ with the finest topology such that the inclusion maps $T_{< N} \hookrightarrow T$ are continuous for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$.
In practice, this means that checking that a map defined on $T$ is continuous only requires checking that its restriction to each homogeneous component is continuous. In the case of $\Gamma \in G$, this reduces to checking that the maps $Q_\eta \Gamma \tau$ are continuous where $\tau \in T_\alpha$ and $\eta \in A$ with $\eta < \alpha$. Here $Q_\eta$ is the obvious projection onto $T_\eta$.
